# Unexpected Behavior with dplyr::filter()

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, tidyverse

thanks for your time.

This is probably an obvious issue I'm overlooking, but I came across some unexpected behavior this morning using `dplyr::filter()`.

Using `filter()` seems to work, except when the column name and the object name are equivalent.  See the below example for details.

I'm expecting `data` to only return the rows where `data$year` matches `year` or `data$month` matches `month`, but it's returning all values instead.

I've done this same operation many times before, so I'm not sure why it's occurring this time.

When renaming `month` to `month_by_a_different_name`, everything works as expected.  Any ideas? Thanks for your time.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Example data
data <-
  tibble(
    year = c(2019, 2018, 2017),
    month = c("January", "February", "March"),
    value = c(1, 2, 3)
  )


# -----------------------------------------------

# Values to filter by
year <- 2019
month <-  "February"

# Assigning year and month to a different object name
year_by_a_different_name <- year
month_by_a_different_name <- month


# -----------------------------------------------

# Filtering using year and month doesn't work
data %>%
  dplyr::filter(year == year)        # Doesn't work

data %>%
  dplyr::filter(month == month)      # Doesn't work


# -----------------------------------------------

# Filtering using different names works
data %>%
  filter(year == year_by_a_different_name)       # Works

data %>% 
  filter(month == month_by_a_different_name)     # Works


# -----------------------------------------------

# Using str_detect() also doesn't work for month
data %>% 
  dplyr::filter(str_detect(month, month))


# -----------------------------------------------

# Works with base R
data[data$month == month, ]
data[data$year == year, ]


# -----------------------------------------------

# Objects are of same class
class(data$year) == class(year)      # TRUE
class(data$month) == class(month)    # TRUE
```

Comment: Ugly but works: `filter(year == .GlobalEnv$year)`. Also, with package `tidyverse` loaded (which loads `dplyr`) you don't need `dplyr::filter`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: use `filter(year == !!year)`

This is caused by dplyr's nonstandard evaluation (NSE) - it's ambiguous whether you're referring to `df$year` or your external variable `year`.
NSE uses so called 'quosures' to infer that when you write `year` on the LHS, you are referring to the column of the column of the pipe-input. This quoting-trick is what allows you to refer to names defined in the scope of the pipe-input (i.e. data frame columns) in the tidyverse family of packages, and makes your life much easier by (i) avoiding having to type quotation-marks everywhere and (ii) allows Rstudio to give you autocomplete suggestions.

However, in your case here, `year` on the RHS is meant to refer to something outside of the input data.frame, even though the name is also used there. In that case, the `!!` ("bangbang") operator tells NSE that your variable should not be quoted, but instead evaluated as is.

You can find more information here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html, especially the section on "Different Expressions". From the vignette above:

> In dplyr (and in tidyeval in general) you use !! to say that you want to unquote an input so that it’s evaluated, not quoted. This gives us a function that actually does what we want.

Answer (score 3):

To evaluate an expression in its original environment you can know where it is defined as in the following, which is not at all pretty.

```
data %>%
  dplyr::filter(year == !!.GlobalEnv$year)
```

Or you can use `enquo`.

```
data %>%
  dplyr::filter(month == !!enquo(month))
```

From the help page `help('enquo')`.

> ## Capture expressions in quosures
>
> `quo()` and `enquo()` are similar to their `expr` counterparts but capture
>   both the expression and its environment in an object called a quosure.
>   This wrapper contains a reference to the original environment in which
>   that expression was captured. Keeping track of the environments of
>   expressions is important because this is where functions and objects
>   mentioned in the expression are defined.
>
> Quosures are objects that can be evaluated with `eval_tidy()` just like
>   symbols or function calls. Since they always evaluate in their
>   original environment, quosures can be seen as vehicles that allow
>   expressions to travel from function to function but that beam back
>   instantly to their original environment upon evaluation.